# Script file set specific date

Tags: scripting

I created a script file that should run every month, but the problem is the date should look like this from - 20170701 - to - 20170801 and the the next month it should run again on this from 20170801 - to - 20170901 and so on.. how do I get this with a script file? here is what I got but this is when I have to put it in manually.

```
echo    "Specify Date Range ... "
echo    " Date From:"
read DATE1
echo    " Date To:"
read DATE2
runcbl -1 -3 uniexp $DATE1$DATE2
```

Okay, thanks for all the help, got it working!

Answer (score 0):

To obtain today's date in the format you specify, use

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

To obtain the date a month earlier, use

```
date +%Y%m%d --date="last month"
```

assuming your system provides GNU `date`, or a `date` with similar free form `--date` argument parsing.

Issue [`man date`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) on your system to get the supported options.

---

If you run your script on the day matching the date you wish used, there is no need to prompt for the date: just incorporate the date string in the script, *e.g.*

```
runcbl -1 -3 uniexp $(date +%Y%m%d) $(date +%Y%m%d --date="last month")
```

Comment: Hi, ok so the command works, the only problem I have is to put a return key after it sets the date? I have tried read c and echo and ^M nothing works, it just adds a empty space after it puts in the date, then I can press manually enter and it goes to the next line.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
clear
cd /u/go
rm -f DET*.INV DET*.PHM HDR*.INV HDR*.PHM
UNICCP=Y ; export UNICCP
echo "Specify Date Range ... "
echo " Date From:"
date +%Y%m%d --date="last month"
read DATE1
echo " Date To:"
date +%Y%m%d
read DATE2
runcbl -1 -3 uniexp $DATE1$DATE2
clear

Comment: @ChristovanRensburg Edited to try to address your question, although I'm not sure I'm correctly reading what you are trying to accomplish.  When clarifying a question, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/384489/edit) the question, rather than adding comments.